# Overview of leaked/unclosed cursors/statements on DB2 LUW server?

Tags: db2, cursors, db2-luw

We're encountering a "too many open cursors issue" on DB2/LUW.

Is there any way to get a (database-server-side) list of the corresponding SELECT statements related to these open cursors?

We're doing that on Oracle all the time.

I know we could review the application logic but that is an awful lot harder in our particular case. So I wanted to get this question out first. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  application_handle
, uow_id, activity_id, activity_type, activity_state
, timestampdiff(2, char(current timestamp - entry_time)) elapsed_sec
, stmt_text
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_ACTIVITY(null, -2))
order by elapsed_sec desc;
```

[MON_GET_ACTIVITY table function - Return a list of activities](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0060766.html)

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Mark's answer you can check for long running transactions:

```
select 
    x.agent_id, 
    substr(z.corr_TOKEN,1,14) as ip,
    cast(y.stmt_text as varchar(800)) as stmt, 
    x.locks_held, 
    x.APPL_IDLE_TIME, 
    x.UOW_START_TIME 
from sysibmadm.SNAPAPPL x 
join sysibmadm.snapstmt y 
    on x.agent_id = y.agent_id 
join sysibmadm.SNAPAPPL_INFO z
    on x.agent_id = z.agent_id
where UOW_STOP_TIME is null 
  and TIMESTAMPDIFF(2,CHAR(current_timestamp - UOW_START_TIME)) > 10
order by UOW_START_TIME
;
```

Beware that cursors declared WITH HOLD may be open after commit